# すべてのブラウザで見られるようにするには？

Tags: javascript, html

下記のソースコードは、マウスストーカーのアナログ時計の外周(DATE)の移動速度を、
セレクトタグで作ったものですが、検索したところ、optionに"onclick"を入れても
IEでは動作しない，と書かれていました(＊一応、動作していますが…？)。
全てのブラウザで見られるようにするには、どのように書き換えたらよろしいのでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=shift_jis"> 

<TITLE>妖怪クロック(アナログ1) - JavaScript</TITLE>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.butt{
BACKGROUND:maroon; 
COLOR:gold;
}
//-->
</style>



 </head>
<BODY bgcolor="black" text="white">

<div id="clock" style="visibility:hidden">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var　　 step=0;　
　　　　currStep=0;
function changeSTEP1(){
step=0.05;
}
function changeSTEP2(){
step=0.02;
}
function changeSTEP3(){
step=0;
}
function changeSTEP4(){
step=-0.02;
}

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }
    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

var dCol = '', //date colour.
    sCol = '', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '', //hours colour.
    fCol = '', //face color

    ClockHeight = 55,
    ClockWidth = 55,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100,
    d = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
    m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    date = new Date(),
    day = date.getDate(),
    year = date.getYear() + 1900;
var TodaysDate = " " + d[date.getDay()] + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year;
var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '☆☆☆';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '☆☆☆☆';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '・・・・・';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.45;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">',
    props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,

    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}
var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';
// Date wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Face wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Hours wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Minute wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Seconds wrapper

html = '';

for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;
// Mouse move event handler

function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}

document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{
    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();

}());

num = 1;
function toggle(){
 num ^= 1; 
 if(num == 1){ 
document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="hidden";
document.getElementById('step').disabled=true;
 }
else { 
document.getElementById('clock').style.visibility="visible";
document.getElementById('step').disabled=false;
} 
document.getElementById("tog").value = num ?" Appear ":"Kill(切る)";
}
</script>


<font id="text1" size="5"><b>妖怪クロック(アナログ１)：</b></font>

<br><br><br>


<div align="center"><div>
<input class="butt" type="button" id="tog" value="今何時？" onclick="toggle()">
</div><br>
<div>
<select id="step" style="background:lightblue" disabled>
<option onClick="changeSTEP1()">FAST</option>
<option onClick="changeSTEP2()">SLOW</option>
<option onClick="changeSTEP3()" selected>ORIGINAL</option>
<option onClick="changeSTEP4()">REVERSE</option>
</select>
</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` の `onchange` を使うのが定番かなと思います。

```
<select id="step" onchange="changeSTEP(this.value)">
  <option value="0.05">FAST</option>
  <option value="0.02">SLOW</option>
  <option value="0" selected>ORIGINAL</option>
  <option value="-0.02">REVERSE</option>
</select>
```

としておいて、
呼び出されたスクリプトでは次の様にします。

```
function changeSTEP(value){
    step = value * 1;//数値に変換
}
```

※セレクトしたアイテムが変化しない場合にはイベントは起こりません。`var step=0;`としているので問題はないはず。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。
"onChange"を使うのが本道のようですので、いろいろ試していたのですが、失敗続きで思いつきでoptionの中にonClickを入れたら、動作下次第です。
"step=value"という図式は、思いつきもしませんでした。
*1;という数字は、何を意味しているのでしょうか。

前にも言っておられましたが、html(初回)とjavascript(2回目以降)にも
disabledを入れておかないと、切っているときも水面下で動作しますよね。

Comment: @user9359  `*1` は、１で掛け算することで文字列を数値に変換してます。 `disabled` に関しては、(`onchange`と)直接関係ない部分なので省略しました。

Comment: 分かりました。
検索しても分からないことも、ここは勉強になります。
これで、また先に進めます。